# Find map between vertex and graph tool index

Tags: graph-tool

I read a graph whose vertices are name of person in graph tool. It assigns its own index to each vertex. I wonder if it is possible to obtain one to one map between vertices original name and their corresponding graph tool index ?

Comment: Of course it is possible. How are you adding the edges?

Comment: my graph is a format of edge list text and I convert if to graph binary

Comment: graph-tool indices are always `0, 1, ..., n-1`. If you are adding edges using `add_edge_list`, then this function would return the vertex labels directly.